# I'm having troubles sending an email from my Laravel 5.3 application

Tags: php, laravel

I want to send emails from my Laravel application but I'm getting this error:

```
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 268: Connection could not be established with host gnom.websitewelcome.com [ #0]
```

This is my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=gnom.websitewelcome.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@hssoluciones.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypass
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

And I'm testing from my web.php file like this:

```
Route::any('mail', function() {
    $cliente = Auth::user();
    Mail::send('backend.emails.bills', 
        [   

        ],
            function ($m) use ($cliente) {
            $m->from('mymail@hssoluciones.com', 'My Name');
            $m->to('someones@mail.com', 'Title')->subject('Foo subject');
        });
});
```

I've tried everything I've read from the differents posts online but I'm getting the same error...

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you tried to connect with some email client, like Thunderbird or Outlook? It works?

Comment: No, but I have access to the webmail and I have the same error.

Comment: You need to contact the administrator to know how to use SMTP on their service.

Comment: The thing is my boss used the same configuration I have in his laptop and did work. So it's really weird.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue within Laravel or your usage of the Swift Mailer. PHP is unable to connect to the SMTP server to deliver the emails. You should one see if you are able to connect to the SMTP server using your local machine. If not, then there is the issue. If you are able to connect then ensure that there is not any firewall blocking that on the server or whitelisting of IPs on the SMTP server side.

Comment: How can I try to connect to the SMTP server in my local machine?

Comment: Any idea on how can I do it?